# “Was a norm for 15 percent of people”

Tags: phrase-request, structure

Is the structure of this scentence sounds natural, or it is odd?

“Eating at fast food restaurants **was a norm for 15% of peole**.”

The context is that I am listing some information according to a study which was done 3 years ago.

Could you help me?

Comment: I'd fix all the typos first...

Comment: Since you are referring to a specific group of people, you should use "was *the* norm".

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer to your question will depend on how people use the word **norm**.

It has two senses, both of **typical practice** and of **a standard**.

So while you can say:

> Eating at fast food restaurants **was normal** for 15% of people

without implying any kind of standard, to use **a norm** is slightly ambiguous.

**A norm** would fit better into a statement such as:

> Giving to charity was a norm for 15% of people

While the example you give is grammatically correct, it is not idiomatic in my experience.

Others may well disagree.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/norm

Comment: What if I changed the original phrase and added “Eating in fast food restaurants twice a week was a norm for 15 percent of people.”? Has it become more idiomatic?

Comment: I can see no difference at all between *eating at fast food restaurants was a norm for 15% of people* and *giving to charity was a norm for 15% of people.* (**X** was a norm for **Y** % of **Z**.) Why are you saying that the second is more natural than the first? (Eating at fast food restaurants rather than not eating at fast food restaurants; giving to charity rather than not giving to charity.) It seems to me they should both be fine or both be awkward. (Personally, I see no problem with either.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't see a problem either but I do see a distinction. While it may be normal for youths to be drunk on a Saturday night, it is unlikely to be described as a norm as the latter may also signify an ethical standard. The norms of society are generally regarded as standards to be aimed for. However, as I concluded, others may well disagree.

Answer (score 0):

Let's actually look at a dictionary definition. According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/norm), **norm** has four different senses:

> **1** : an authoritative standard : MODEL
>   **2** : a principle of right action binding upon the members of a group and serving to guide, control, or regulate proper and acceptable behavior
>   • No society lacks *norms* governing conduct. —Robert K. Merton 
>   **3** : average: such as
>   **a** : a set standard of development or achievement usually derived from the average or median achievement of a large group
>   **b** : a pattern or trait taken to be typical in the behavior of a social group • studies aimed at establishing the *norms* of sexual behavior among the middle classes
>   **c** : a widespread or usual practice, procedure, or custom • standing ovations became the *norm* • Bilingualism is the *norm* in many countries.
>   **4 a** : a real-valued nonnegative function defined on a vector space with value analogous to length and satisfying the conditions that the function is zero if and only if the vector (see <sup>1</sup>VECTOR 1a) is zero, the function of the product of a scalar and a vector is equal to the product of the absolute value of the scalar and the function of the vector, and the function of the sum of two vectors is less than or equal to the sum of the functions of the two vectors; *specifically* : the square root of the sum of the squares of the absolute values of the elements of a matrix (see MATRIX 5a) or of the components of a vector
>   **b** : the greatest distance between two successive points of a set of points that partition an interval (see INTERVAL 2a) into smaller intervals

- In terms of sense 1, there could be a social or cultural model that says 15% of a certain group of people eat at fast food restaurants.
- In terms of sense 2, it certainly seems like acceptable social behaviour for 15% of a a group of people to eat at fast food restaurants. Normal societies likely have all sort of things that you'd expect a percentage of them to engage (or not engage) in. And remember that this is only the norm for 15% of the people in the group—not for all of them.
- In terms of sense 3, as a statistical study, it's very reasonable to assume that surveys show that 15% of a group of people actually do eat at fast food restaurants.
- I very strongly doubt that the study made use of sense 4, so it can be discounted.

Whether or not 15% is an accurate value, I would say that **norm** is being used in a reasonable way.

I presume that the three-year-old study will have put the word into actual context so that its actual sense was apparent.

In terms of the structure of the sentence itself, I would echo a comment that it would more commonly be *the norm*.